# How to write dynamically merged number of images and store into one single image in application folder asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

In my application, I have number of images in my application folder i need to merge into a single image when i tried  code that is i take statically. I need to how dynamically take my code for combining images into a single image and store it in application folder.

My code:
.cs

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string img1path = MapPath("~/AppImages/12162016/ScnMeet1.PNG");


        // Load two Images to be combined into Image Objects 
        System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img1path);          

  var images = new[] { img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7 };
        using (Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(images.Max(img => img.Width), images.Sum(img => img.Height)))
        {
            using (Graphics FinalImage = Graphics.FromImage(FinalBitmap))
            {
                // Draw the first image staring at point (0,0) with actual width and height of the image, in final image
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img1, new Rectangle(0, 0, img1.Width, img1.Height));
                // and Draw the second image staring at point where first image ends in the final image and save changes
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img2, 0, img1.Height);
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img3, 0, img1.Height + img2.Height);
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img4, 0, img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height);
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img5, 0, img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height + img4.Height);
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img6, 0, img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height + img4.Height + img5.Height);
                FinalImage.DrawImage(img7, 0, img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height + img4.Height + img5.Height + img6.Height);

                FinalImage.Save();
                // Write the bitmap to an image file and you’re done
                FinalBitmap.Save(MapPath("~/ResultImages/Resultimg.PNG"));
                MergedCombinedImage.ImageUrl = "~/ResultImages/Resultimg.PNG";
            }
        }
    }
```

with the above code i have 7 images i take 7 image path.If i have 15 images i will take 15 image path i think it is not correct but how can i take dynamically any one please give me idea to make dynamically.
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdm9A.png)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be using the [*params* keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) combined with an *foreach loop* in an static method for this.

Disclaimer, this is an **not an working** code (just a guideline in an direction):

```
static void MergeImages(params Image[] images)  //allows a variable number of arguments 
{
    int currentImgHeight = 0;

    using (Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(images.Max(img => img.Width), images.Sum(img => img.Height)))
    {
        using (Graphics FinalImage = Graphics.FromImage(FinalBitmap))
        {
            foreach (var img in images)
            {
                currentImgHeight += img.Height; //counter upwards for height

                FinalImage.DrawImage(img, img.Width, currentImgHeight);
            }

            FinalImage.Save();

            FinalBitmap.Save(MapPath("~/ResultImages/Resultimg.PNG"));
            MergedCombinedImage.ImageUrl = "~/ResultImages/Resultimg.PNG";
        }
    }
}
```

Possible example calling:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/AppImages/12162016/"));
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
}
MergeImages(images.ToArray());
```

Comment: @User805 Updated calling of method.

Comment: Hi,Smartis, `FinalImage.DrawImage(img, img.Width, currentImgHeight);` i tried with this images are not display when i changed the code to `FinalImage.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, currentImgHeight));` like this the result my folder contains 7 images it displayed merged 2 images and images are not display clarity it display please tell me how to changes final image width and height.Thank you

Comment: I added my result image at last with the caption of `image description here` can you please see once

Comment: No @Smartis I updated my result image images display not in clarity and in my folder 7 images it displays only 1 r 2 with no clarity can you please tell me